# Fetch an image in a specific folder in OneDrive/SharePoint via PowerShell or Azure Logicapp

Tags: powershell, sharepoint-online, onedrive, azure-logic-apps

I have a Microsoft Form that can be filled with an attachment before sending:

[image]

During testing I realized uploaded content was always sent to the same folder inside the receiver's personal OneDrive.

Knowing OneDrive and SharePoint are basically the same I attempted to use the SharePoint PS Module for testing to see if I could fetch the most recent image, but nothing worked.

I need to be able to retrieve the most recent image in a static folder in OneDrive and save it so I can forward it in the same snippet of code via a POST request. Is that possible? My idea would be to somehow use logicapps to access the folder and retrieve the image if through PS that isn't possible.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Yea, your Logic of Sharepoint and OneDrive being same is correct - However,you would need access to the OneDrive in order fetch the image. OneDrive site  bydefault will be given access to only the owner of the site.

You could use logic app /PowerShell to do the same - but please note you would need access to the same.

**Alternate Suggestion :**

Also, Logic App / Flow has a trigger - **when a response is received**

Response body will have the image.  You can handle/extract the response body.

Came across almost a similar requirement that was handled using suggested logic :  [MS Forms Flow Image Capture](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Flows/MS-Forms-flow-that-captures-image-and-adds-to-SharePoint-list/td-p/467554)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I actually managed to pull the image using Microsoft's Graph API and querying the OneDrive folder directly for the most recent image. My issue now is with Azure runbooks. For some reason I can pull the image locally and pass the file path with the OutFile parameter of Invoke-RestMethod, however this does not work in an Azure runbooks as is keeps returning a 400 when pulling the image back to send it as -OutFile to the graph API. I'm currently on my phone so I can't link it but if you could take a look at my other stack overflow thread regarding that I'd be very thankful

Comment: Here it is: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66643841/azure-powershell-runbook-infile-flag-of-invoke-restmethod-not-working-as-inten