# Azure PowerShell runbook: -InFile flag of Invoke-RestMethod not working as intended

Tags: azure, powershell, microsoft-graph-api

I'm creating an Azure runbook script that fetches an image and then sends it again via http to update a specific company user's profile picture. The relevant documentation says that the worker that runs the runbook has a temporary storage that is accessible and indeed I can see the file downloads there, but then when specifying its path via -InFile it keeps returning a 400 and on postman it works perfectly, so does locally via my own computer's PowerShell. Here's the code:

```
## Begin fetching auth2.0 token ##

## Fetch user

$boundary = [System.Guid]::NewGuid().ToString(); 
$LF = "`r`n";

# Because the workers run an earlier version of PowerShell I had to declare the form in this 
jibberish way, as per another stackoverflow thread. However this works and the auth2.0 is retrieved.

$bodyLines = ( 
    "--$boundary",
    "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=`"grant_type`"$LF",
    "client_credentials$LF",
    "--$boundary",
    "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=`"client_id`"$LF",
    "[client_id]$LF",
    "--$boundary",
    "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=`"scope`"$LF",
    "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default$LF",
    "--$boundary",
    "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=`"client_secret`"$LF",
    "[client_secret]$LF",
    "--$boundary--$LF" 
) -join $LF

$AuthTokenRequestHeaders = @{
    "Cache-Control" = "no-cache"
}

$AuthTokenResponse = Invoke-RestMethod 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/[company-name].onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/v2.0/token' -Method 'POST' -ContentType "multipart/form-data; boundary=`"$boundary`"" -Body $bodyLines -Headers $AuthTokenRequestHeaders

$authToken = $AuthTokenResponse.access_token

#### Finish token fetching ####


# Get user-specific Microsoft Object ID
$MsolCred = Get-AutomationPSCredential -Name "Office365"
Connect-MsolService -Credential $MsolCred -AzureEnvironment "AzureCloud"
$MsolUserId = (Get-MsolUser -UserPrincipalName $Email).ObjectId.Guid


#### Begin updating profile picture ####
$RequestHeader = @{
    "Authorization" = "Bearer $authToken"
    "Content-Type" = "image/jpeg"
}

# Look at contents on static OneDrive folder
$OneDriveFolderContents = (Invoke-RestMethod -Uri 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drives/[drive-id]/items/[folder-id]/children' -Method Get -Headers $RequestHeader)

# Logic to look for the most recent file
$MostRecentFileDate = 0;
$MostRecentFileId = "";

foreach ($file in $OneDriveFolderContents.value) {

    if ($file.createdDateTime -gt $MostRecentFileDate) {
        $MostRecentFileDate = $file.createdDateTime
        $MostRecentFileId = $file.id
    }

}

# GET for most recent image
$restById = (Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drives/[drive-id]/items/$mostRecentFileId/content" -Method Get -Headers $RequestHeader -OutFile "profilepicture.jpeg") 


# This section was for debugging purposes. Checking if the file was downloaded correctly and its path in the runbook worker who's running the script. Because workers only have one randomly named folder and a folder named "diags" I just exclude the diags folder and look for it inside the temporary folder after finding its name
$var1 =  (Get-ChildItem -Path 'C:\Temp\' -Depth 2).Directory
$var2 = ""

foreach ($folder in $var1) {

    if ($folder.Name -ne "diags") {
        $var2 = $folder.Name
    }
    
}

Write-Output "Found folder named $var2 to use in path"

## End debugging section


$forinfile = "C:\Temp\$var2\profilepicture.jpeg"

# This confirms that the file is indeed there
Write-Output (Get-ChildItem -Path C:\Temp\ -Depth 2)

# PUT most recent image to the specific user
$userUrlString = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/" + $MsolUserId + '/photo/$value'

# This is the specific Invoke-RestMethod that returns a 400. Following are 4 different ones I tried with no success
Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $userUrlString -Method Put -Headers $RequestHeader -InFile "$forinfile"
Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $userUrlString -Method Patch -Headers $RequestHeader -InFile "profilepicture.jpeg"
Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $userUrlString -Method Put -Headers $RequestHeader -InFile "profilepicture.jpeg"
Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $userUrlString -Method Patch -Headers $RequestHeader -InFile "$forinfile"
```

The code works perfectly on my own machine, but on Azure it keeps returning the same error:

[image]

Here are some additional debugging outputs from past runs that confirm FOR SURE the file is there:

[image]

To answer what I think may be the first thing wondered: on Azure AD the auth2.0 token and its respective application have been configured to allow a profile picture update on behalf of someone else. Locally on my own machine I was able to change a coworker's picture.

Answer (score 0):

I use your script and it works fine in Azure Automation Runbook from my side.

Since the jpeg file is successfully downloaded, the issue should lie on the last Graph call.

To troubleshooting this issue, you **don't** need to use:

```
$MsolCred = Get-AutomationPSCredential -Name "Office365"
Connect-MsolService -Credential $MsolCred -AzureEnvironment "AzureCloud"
$MsolUserId = (Get-MsolUser -UserPrincipalName $Email).ObjectId.Guid
$userUrlString = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/" + $MsolUserId + '/photo/$value'
```

Just use `$userUrlString = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/" + $Email + '/photo/$value'` directly.

Let me know if it works.

Comment: Thanks Allen, I found the issue in the meantime. Apparently it was a problem with the version of the modules used on Azure. After updating to the latest version everything ran perfectly

Comment: @Ress Glad to know this issue is resolved:)